# Trigger INSERT SQL multiple data

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger with sql so that When I insert a row in Point I insert before it a row in PointAbs.

```
CREATE TABLE PointAbs (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    X INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Y INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Point(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(50) ,
    IDPointAbs INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPointAbs) REFERENCES PointAbs(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

the problem is that I need to provide *"X"* and *"Y"* for **PointAbs** and *"Name"* for **Point** at the same time. Ho can I achieve that?
I could use a **JDBC** functionality to get the last insertedID but I don't like it that way.

Comment: you cant do that IDPointAbs is to be inserted in Point and it refernces the autoincremented value in Points Abs ID column!!!!

Comment: Besides i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @nikhilsugandh is right but you can "cheat" your way around it by adding a 0 id in the PointAbs  and use the 0 as IDPointAbs in the Point insert query.. But using id 0 is a bit counteractive in SQL

Comment: @RaymondNijland how its autoincremented??? default 0??

Comment: true @nikhilsugandh "cheat" again lock the table PointAbs for read and write, get the current auto_increment value from the information_schema.TABLES view, ALTER the column id to remove the AUTO_INCREMENT, add the insert with id, ALTER the column again so it has the auto_increment again, ALTER the table AUTO_INCREMENT value with the last value and unlock the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the relation is 1 to 1, as you have to create a new PointAbs for each Point. Unless you have another table that relates to PintAbs, there will be one PointAbs for each Point. If you don't need two separated objects, you can state X and Y as an index of Point:

```
CREATE TABLE Point(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(50) ,
    IDPointAbs INTEGER NOT NULL,
    X INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Y INTEGER NOT NULL,
    INDEX INDEX_X_Y ON Point(X,Y)
);
```

Of course, this might not be possible nor desirable in your design.
As you can't send parameters to the trigger like the X and Y values, your best option is to use a single transaction for both inserts.

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO PointAbs(X,Y) VALUES (10,15);
    INSERT INTO Point(Name, IDPointAbs) VALUES ('Fancy Name', LAST_INSERT_ID(PointAbs));
COMMIT;
```

You can control the insertions using the programming language of the system back-end, but as there is no specific language mentioned other than mysql, I won't enter into details.

Comment: I understand what you're saying @Beto Raposa
But unfortunately I have other relations with PointAbs, that's why I'm separating the two tables.